# System of equations with unknowns in R

Tags: r, equation, equation-solving

I have a 3x3 matrix Omega whose elements are unknown, and a defined 3x1 parameter vector alpha. I want to define a 3x1 vector delta whose elements are still unknown but depend on alpha and Omega as shown in this image:

[image: Formula]

The term in the brackets to the power of 2 simplifies to a number K, so I wrote this function:

```
Alpha=c(-0.248,1.092,-0.518)
K=function(gamma1,gamma2,gamma3,gamma12,gamma23,gamma13){
    (1+Alpha[1]*(Alpha[1]+Alpha[2]*gamma12/(gamma1*gamma2)+Alpha[3]*gamma13/(gamma1*gamma3)))^(-1/2)
    }
```

`gamma1, gamma2, gamma3` are the elements in the diagonal of the 3x3 matrix Omega, whereas `gamma12, gamma13, gamma23` are the off-diagonal elements (each elements repeats itself twice, e.g. `gamma12=gamma21`). So, by putting 6 arbitrary values in `K()` I get the scalar. So far so clear.

The rest I'm not sure about. I want R to return me a vector delta defined as shown above. How can I write a function that would perform this algebraic calculation, and return a 3x1 vector delta whose elements are the same unknowns as in Omega, but shifted/multiplied by the numbers in alpha?

Comment: Write the equation in plain text, there is a problem with the sharing, is asking for user and password.

Comment: Hi @Robert, I added the formula in text right under the link. Hope you understand what I mean with the formula, otherwise let me know!

Comment: Are you trying to perform symbolic algebra? (I.e., you want the answer in terms of unevaluated variables?)

Comment: yes! I have these 6 unknowns in the 3x3 matrix omega, and through the calculation illustrated above (thanks @snoram for the edit suggestion) I want to be able to define the 3 elements of the 3x1 vector delta as function of omega, or as algebraic expression containing the unevaluated elements of omega. thanks for replying, hope this is doable in R

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?:

```
#generate the triangular matrix
set.seed(234)
og<-matrix(runif(9,1,2),3)
og[lower.tri(og)] = t(og)[lower.tri(og)]
#K(og[1,1],og[2,2],og[3,3],og[1,2],og[2,3],og[1,3])

#delta = (1 + alpha' * Omega * alpha)^(-1/2) * Omega * alpha
as.numeric((1+Alpha%*%og%*%Alpha)^(-1/2))*og%*%Alpha

> as.numeric((1+Alpha%*%og%*%Alpha)^(-1/2))*og%*%Alpha
           [,1]
[1,]  0.7264204
[2,] -0.2365427
[3,]  0.5709528
```

## Edit

If you want a function

```
Kf=function(gamma1,gamma2,gamma3,gamma12,gamma23,gamma13,Alphav=Alpha){
  ogm<-matrix(c(gamma1,gamma12,gamma13,gamma12,gamma2,gamma23,
                gamma13,gamma23,gamma3),3)
  KF<-as.numeric((1+t(Alphav)%*%ogm%*%Alphav)^(-1/2))
  Delt<-KF*ogm%*%Alphav
  list(Delta=Delt,K=KF,Om=ogm)
}

#taking the same random values for consistency
gamma1=og[1,1]; gamma2=og[2,2]; gamma3=og[3,3];
gamma12=og[1,2]; gamma23=og[2,3]; gamma13=og[1,3]

Kf(gamma1,gamma2,gamma3,gamma12,gamma23,gamma13)$Delta

> Kf(gamma1,gamma2,gamma3,gamma12,gamma23,gamma13)$Delta
           [,1]
[1,]  0.7264204
[2,] -0.2365427
[3,]  0.5709528
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I meant something a bit different. If omega is known then yes, that's what I'd like to do. The thing is, omega is unknown. In the matrix omega I have 6 unknowns (since some repeat themselves), in vector alpha 3 known numbers. I need an expression of delta as a function of (og[1,1], ..., og[1,3]), which I can later use in a second equation, which equates Omega and a transformation of delta to a matrix I fully know. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for (see Gregor's comment), but thank you for your efforts and replies. Actually you gave me some inputs for something I'm gonna need later in my code. Thanks :) (sorry I can't upvote your answer, I tried to but apparently I need a reputation of 15 to upvote)